# HAML can not show any string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I followed [calendar](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised?view=asciicast)

Try to show calendar in my page,

index.haml

```
%div#articles
  - calendar do |date|
    - p(date.to_s)
    %b= date.day
```

I can get the output `- p(date.to_s)`  from console

```
"2014-03-30"
"2014-03-31"
"2014-04-01"
"2014-04-02"
...
```

But get nothing from the HTML

```
<div id="articles">
</div>
```

Comment: And what happens when you do `= date.to_s` instead of `- p(date.to_s)` ? What does p(..) do? Is `calendar do |date|` correct? Don't you need to do something like `calendar.each do |date|`

Comment: print date.to_s will show "2014-03-30" in console

Comment: And what happens when you put `%b= date.to_s` instead of `%b= date.day` ?